# Index of research papers with ready bibitems

Tags: bibliographies

I have a URL of a paper in pdf. Is there a place that I can obtain ready `\bibitem` for this paper? I don't want to include neither only the URL of the paper nor list of all authors, dates, etc. myself.

EDIT: Having read the comments and following advise on how to use `biblatex` from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management#Modern_style_.28biblatex.29) I have create the following structure (which still does not produce the bibliography correctly):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% everything that this documentclass requires
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/files/dcsbook.cls
http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/files/dcslib.sty

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% thesis.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,thesis]{dcsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\author{YYY}
\title{XXX}
\supervisor{ZZZ}
\date{Poznań, 2014}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents{}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

aa \cite{StoicaChord}  bbbb

\backmatter

\printbibliography

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% references.bib
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@article{StoicaChord,
        Author = {Ion Stoica and Robert Morris and David Liben{-}Nowell and David R. Karger and M. Frans Kaashoek and Frank Dabek and Hari Balakrishnan},
        Bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org},
        Biburl = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/journals/ton/StoicaMLKKDB03},
        Date-Modified = {2014-10-15 01:28:44 +0000},
        Doi = {10.1109/TNET.2002.808407},
        Journal = {{IEEE/ACM} Trans. Netw.},
        Number = {1},
        Pages = {17--32},
        Timestamp = {Wed, 15 Oct 2014 01:53:37 +0200},
        Title = {Chord: a scalable peer-to-peer lookup protocol for internet applications},
        Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNET.2002.808407},
        Volume = {11},
        Year = {2003},
        Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNET.2002.808407}}
```

The `.tex` files complies itself to pdf, but the bibliography is not present in the output. The reference to the only one bibliography item, instead of being rendered as a number, this is [**1**], is rendered as follows: [**StoicaChord**].

Comment: Google scholar would be an option. For computer science you can use DBLP http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/ . You will get the `bib` record.

Comment: Standard practice is to maintain a database of the publications that you cite and then use bibtex/biblatex/biber/... to create your bibliographies. See [bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) for details.

Comment: Guido - thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Andrew - I starting playing with that by creating a .bib file with list of @articles. I have come across one problem, I have used so far normal bibitems like this: 
\bibitem{python}\emph{https://www.python.org/}. Now, when I want to include items both old way (because not every item is a paper) and the more verbose ones, I am getting conflicts. Is there any common way to handle that?

Comment: If you are writing a `.bib` file, you should never type `\bibitem` at all. (I have never used `\bibitem` in a document of my own.) You also don't (generally) want formatting such as `\emph` in there. At least, it should be a last resort.

Comment: @cfr I see, then I will move all \bibitems to the .bib file. At the moment my bibliography structure is as follows:
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
% peer-to-peer
\bibitem{}\emph{http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/ton:chord/paper-ton.pdf}
% twisted purpose
\bibitem{twisted}\emph{https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/}

\end{thebibliography}

and if I understand correctly, now I only have to include these:
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{<my_bib_file1>, <my_bib_file2>},
where these files include definitions of @article/@misc and I am ready to go. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends. Are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex`? For `bibtex`, that's right. For `biblatex`, that's wrong. The bit about the `.bib` entries replacing the need for `\bibitem` is correct either way. Just `\bibliographystyle` is `bibtex` only.

Comment: @cfr - I am using biblatex. I deleted the line with \bibliographystyle and at least the .tex file compiles, but bibliography does not work properly. I am not sure if I still have to define \thebibliography{1} or not. This is how I am trying to do it: http://pastebin.com/8Xe3apEv.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you load the `biblatex` package? No. You don't define `\thebibliography`. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And do read the link Andrew posted above.

Comment: @cfr - I provided an example, please see my post. DocumentClass specified in the example comes from here: http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/files/dcsbook.cls

Comment: Please edit your question to include your MWE here. Otherwise, your question only has meaning or value for future users until your pastebin expires.

Comment: @cfr You're right, thanks for hints. I've updated the question. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should move your bibliography to its own file with the extension bib. E.i `references.bib`, but in the same folder. Second, in biblatex (opposite bibtex) you need to add the file extension to your reference. The correct way to include the file is

```
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```